# Android listview with custom layout header and footer

Tags: android, listview

Sory I can't describe a right title for my question,

I want to create listview something like this

[image]

In top of list view on screen look like

[image]

and when user scroll the list in screen will be like this

[image]

and in end of list is

[image]

I have 3 picture for top list, middle and bottom list.
I already try to add header and footer for top image and bottom image but looks like the picture is inside the list view

I try to create vertical linear layout and put picture top,middle and bottom in sequence but still not get result that i expected

Do anyone have a suggestion for listview like this

Comment: Post your vertical LinearLayout xml, it should work imo.

Comment: maybe you should use 9patch image for listVeiw background , top and boottom will be unstretchable area (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: You can use two ImageViews and in between use the List
so u can easily set images to those two ImageViews which u want

Comment: @Mickey : yes it should be strech but i dont know why its can't strech, i check at draw9patch and check show content but when i put on android:background in list view, the result bottom image is showing at first

Answer (score 0):

Don't set your frame background for entire listview or its parent. Instead first slice your frame background into three parts, (i) topframe (ii) middleframe (iii) bottomframe. Now create a custom listview and set background for each and every list rows.

In order to achieve your design, you need to find the first and last item of list and set topframe for first row and bottomframe for last row , all the other rows background should be middleframe.